# Where did this answer go?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

Just interested in what happened, why would someone delete their accepted answer to my question [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201952/) that actually helped me?

And isn't ACuriousMind's comment just wrong?

Comment: so why is [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205524/hermitian-2x2-matrix-in-terms-of-pauli-matrices), where someone just want's some proof not closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was deleted by a [moderator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) in accordance with the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/2451), under which full/explicit answers to homework-like questions get deleted.

Comment: (And yes, my comment needs a ${}^*$ complex conjugation on the trace to be correct for non-self-adjoint operators, it nevertheless contains the essential idea of the proof)

Comment: Well It did not help me. And it appears that super operators are a bit more complicated than just some trace identity

Comment: Sorry but this makes me really angry since the answer actually helped me...

Comment: not sure why but this waste of time and effort for some dubious rule just makes me fume. Who is helped by not explaining something?

Comment: @pindakaas: The [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/50583) has been extensively debated on this meta, just look at the questions tagged [tag:homework].

Comment: That's what t thought. Lucky for me I wrote the thing down on paper so no harm done but to future people searching this site...

Comment: @pindakaas Harm *is* done whenever we let violations of the policy stick around. Sure, *you* may be better off if we just cater to your every whim. But the health of this site, the participation of experts, the quality of the questions asked -- these will all suffer in the long run if we don't have filters in place. There are plenty of other sites on the internet that value individuals' selfishness over community quality -- you are free to go to them if you want.

Comment: Cater to my whim? What are you so salty about? The answer helped me, would have helped other people and now it's gone. The work that went into writing it too. If helping people is selfisness than I like being selfish ^^ and people who are.

Comment: @pindakaas We get "salty" as you put it because the site is not intended to help answer homework questions. We just don't want that here, even if it helps people. Dropping in to ask for help on physics homework is just as off-topic as dropping in to ask for an awesome apple pie recipe. The site isn't intended to answer those questions, we don't want to answer those questions, and we don't want people asking them -- apple pie, fixing a car, building a cabinet, and asking physics homework questions are just not what is desired here.

Comment: well some people appear to want to answer them. So there you are mistaken. But okay if you consider this homework like then I will refrain from asking such things in the future. I still don't see the point of denying people who want to help and people who need help... Still what's with the apple pie talk why do you guys have to be so intense about it?

Comment: @pindakaas [take a read](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6706/23473). It's more about "check-my-work" questions, but the points remain valid. It helps students, but this site is for practiced physicists. If we let in questions about homework, then we have evidence from other sites that experts and practiced physicists would tend to abandon us. We want this to be high quality and for physicists, so we keep homework help questions off-topic because they don't cater to our intended audience

Comment: @tpg2114 I have an awesome apple pie recipe if you want to swap recipes. One of the secrets is to use ginger ale instead of water

Comment: @Jim Well I think the "only professional questions" boat has sailed a long time ago.^^ look at the questions page and tell me that "How to make two equations dimensionless?" "Why array of telescope is used?" "Push a Boeing 737 on ice: Did this guy have a chance?" are questions from working physicist on their work. Are you kidding?^^

Comment: @pindakaas it's true, we are a bit lenient by our own choice. However, notice that we always restrict questions to at least be about physics concepts or the application of physics concepts to situations from everyday life. Our long standing policy has always discluded explicit questions about the solution to homework-like problems. We may be lenient one way towards less "professional" questions, but that is entirely up to our discretion.

Comment: @pindakaas We are professional physicists that *volunteer* to answer other people's questions about physics. We answer what we choose to answer and deny what we choose to deny. If someone offers you a free cookie, do you complain and berate them because you wanted a muffin? We give out free cookies, but we don't make muffins. You can either take a cookie and be grateful, or don't. I'm sure people *would* benefit from a free muffin, but we don't make them. Why are you getting angry that we aren't *volunteering* our time to help people solve homework-like problems?

Comment: Yeah but waiting untill there is an answer and then delete it? I just don't see the point in this waste of time and work.

Comment: Have you read the title? even The discussion we were having in the comments was deleted. This is why I opended this Question not because I want someone to answer my question.

Comment: @pindakaas We discourage those answers. We say "don't give full solutions in an answer or in the comments". When that happens, it's a violation of policy and we delete it. Usually, the question is closed before an answer can be given, sometimes one slips through and action is taken

Comment: Well don't put words in peoples moth then...